# How can I count the number of movies that are being watched in every hour when I have a table that contains movies start and end times?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a table that looks like:

```
start_timestamp        end_timestamp
2012-11-18 05:53:36.0  2012-11-18 7:46:40.0
2012-11-18 06:34:23.0  2012-12-18 09:21:57.0
```

And I want the output to look like:

```
hour                   moves_being_played
2012-11-18 05:00:00.0  1
2012-11-18 06:00:00.0  2
2012-11-18 07:00:00.0  2
2012-11-18 08:00:00.0  1
2012-11-18 09:00:00.0  1
```

So far I've tried manually setting the value for each hour and counting the number of movies that have a lower start time and a higher end time.

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(start_time) < 6 THEN 1 ELSE null END)
COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(start_time) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE null END) - COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(end_time) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE null END)
...
COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(start_time) < 9 THEN 1 ELSE null END) - COUNT(CASE WHEN HOUR(end_time) < 9 THEN 1 ELSE null END)
FROM table
```

How can I do this without manually setting each hour period and with the result being a "long" rather than "wide" table?

Comment: Please tag with db platform, and what have you tried?

Comment: Whey they say "what have you tried", they mean paste the ACTUAL code that you've tried in the question...

Comment: this is an article geared towards sql server, but it could give you some ideas for your problem. http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/create-date-time-intervals-table-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: do you have a table with all possible timestamps?

Comment: @vkp No, I do not but it looks like the link that Jeremy posted could be used to create one (assuming it can be rewritten for HiveQL or SparkSQL from SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be:

i generate all full hours of a day recursively and join the result with the movie table

```
with mycte as
(
    SELECT CAST('00:00:00' as time)  AS MyHour
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 1, MyHour)
    FROM mycte 
    WHERE  MyHour < '23:00:00'
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS movies_being_played
      ,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), yourmovietable.start_timestamp, 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), mycte.MyHour, 108))
  FROM mycte
  INNER JOIN yourmovietable
  ON mycte.MyHour BETWEEN CAST(yourmovietable.start_timestamp as time) 
                      AND CAST(yourmovietable.end_timestamp as time)                   
 GROUP BY CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), yourmovietable.start_timestamp, 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), mycte.MyHour, 108))
```